# Odoo Decrease Product Quantity Programmatically

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have created a custom module where there is a field related to `product`. When the user checkout the product in the custom module, I want to decrease the quantity of product in the override create method. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution code

```
warehouse = self.env['stock.warehouse'].search(
    [('company_id', '=', self.env.company.id)], limit=1
)

self.env['stock.quant'].with_context(inventory_mode=True).create({
    'product_id': product_id,
    'location_id': warehouse.lot_stock_id.id,
    'inventory_quantity': new_quantity,
})
```